# How to make the event handler non-blocking in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, event-handling, dom-events

Here, If you typed a key in the input and look at the browser console, you can see that the typed letter will appear here after the execution of the for-loop. **How can I make the letter appeared instantly?**

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', () => {
  for(let i=0; i<=1000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: What is `.target-input`?

Comment: instead of JQuery, try adding `oninput="searchHabdler()"` on the input tag itself

Comment: Actually, `.target-input` is the input field, from which I am reading search-keyword.
And `searchHandler` is the function which is searching the matched words and highlighting them.

Comment: Javascript is a single threaded language. From what I can guess, searchHandler is not an async function, so its blocking the rest of execution of the application. Try making searchHandler an async function.

Comment: Tried js native `oninput` event with addEventListener. But still no improvement :(

Comment: Could you actually add the code that has an issue (html for target-input, js for searchHandler) instead of showing us something that clearly has not issues on its own?

Comment: fyi, `input` event is non cancellable.

Comment: Please **update your question** with the necessary code to get a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) going. We cannot help you if you only provide a small detail of your problem. Yes we know that `searchHabdler` is a function, but what does it do?

Comment: Hello guys. Sorry for not adding a reproducible example with the question. I just added an example at the end of the question. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: try using onKeyUp event instead

Comment: What is the reason for doing such heavy load on each input change? Can't you just use the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event, or if there are more fields do it on [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)? If this isn't possible for some reason i suggest looking into [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try?

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', async () => {
      for(let i=0; i<=1000; i++) {
        console.log(i);
      }
 })
```

Apparently your callback is blocking execution of thread, that would be the reason that it has to wait until for loop is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried this. But no improvement. :(

Comment: `async` is just a syntax sugar for hiding the continuation of one or multiple promises. It's not magic, there is no `await` or promises here so there is no point in having `async`.